# Need to point to files outside the www root

Tags: iis

My problem is as follows, I am running a website on a window server. The websites are located in the following directory. 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/'.

The c drive has become very full recently as one of the websites allows the user to upload files to this location 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/mywebsite/recordings/'.

I would like to move this recordings folder the e drive on the server which has lots of space 'e:/mywebsite_data/recordings/'

I created this folder and have moved the files to there new location on the e drive.

My problem is I cannot create a hyper link to the files on this new location. I have tried this href below but obviously this is looking for a file on my own workstation.

```
<a href="E:\mywebsite_data\recordings\F1301210919031721005a.wav">Recording</a>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can solve your problem by creating a virtual directory

[Creating Virtual Directories in IIS 6.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20150311170549/http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx?mfr=true)

Here is an article on how to do this in IIS7

[Understanding Sites, Applications, and Virtual Directories on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis-7/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use IIS' virtual directories: https://web.archive.org/web/20110318232846/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138

With them you can place external folders in your website (it's like an include).

**Update:**

Another tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx