# Send Folders(or Files) to Server from ASP.NET Core MVC using C#

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-services

I have a hosted ASP.NET Core MVC web application with IIS in Windows Server 2019.

We have a scenario to send files from the logged in user's `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Files` folder to a server (`wwwroot` folder).

Currently we use this code:

```
string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

but it's returning the server's local path instead of logged-in user path.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I think you cannot, you have to ask user to upload files

Comment: @vivek-nuna, programmatically can't we upload without user 
interaction?

Comment: Don’t you think it will be user’s privacy violation?

Comment: @vivek-nuna, user will give full access permission to send to server

Comment: @Ra_g it seems there is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788631/need-to-point-to-files-outside-the-www-root

Comment: A IIS server is well protected and you cannot access the file system on the server.  Instead you must use a network drive that uses have read/write access.